What's the difference between the "approaching minimums" and "plus hundred" callout for Boeing aircraft?
Is it essentially the same thing? And if so, does it vary based on the model of Boeing aircraft or airline's choice?

EGPWS callouts are selectable by customers, e.g. for Honeywell MK V and MK VII:

Mode 6 provides EGPWS advisory callouts based on the
menu-selected option established at installation (set by
program pin configuration). These callouts consist of
predefined Radio Altitude based voice callouts or tones and an
excessive bank angle advisory.

Among the choices:

“APPROACHING DECISION HEIGHT” or “PLUS HUNDRED” correspond to DH+100ft

“APPROACHING MINIMUMS” corresponds to DH+80ft.


Customers can also request specific callouts, e.g. DH+60ft (more).
